# Отбор значений в DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм. Нужно оставить только строки по определенному условию.

```
Признак
12
12
132
12
12карат
карат, 12
ка
```

Нужно оставить те строки, где будут только цифры.
Получиться должно примерно так

```
Признак
12
12
132
12
```

Либо например оставить только строки с определенным количеством символов, например два символа. Получится примерно так.

```
Признак
12
12
12
ка
```

Также можно комбо-условие : только две цифры, тогда получится вот так:

```
Признак
12
12
12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, это всё про одно и тоже - отбор по регулярному выражению. Можно делать при помощи метода pd.Series.str.match

```
df[df['Признак'].str.match('^\d+$')]
df[df['Признак'].str.match('^.{2}$')]
df[df['Признак'].str.match('^\d{2}$')]
```